# Replace the mixed pattern with preg_replace() on a directory path string

Tags: preg-replace

I want to remove "Documents/1/project/1/sub/15/"
from the whole text srting
"Documents/1/project/1/sub/15/Project 1_1/2012-09-10/0a/0ad0175615742c7a3142cd0ecc4c3277/19-50-24-10233310.txt"

But the numbers 1,1 and 15 will not be same always.It will change.

Desired result : "Project 1_1/2012-09-10/0a/0ad0175615742c7a3142cd0ecc4c3277/19-50-24-10233310.txt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

preg_replace('/(Documents/.+?)+(/project/.+?)+(/sub/.+?)+(/)/i','',$str)